# [buildfarm] dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library

Tags: ros, buildfarm, jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to release paho.mqtt.cpp as a dependency of one of our packages.

If fails on the error: `dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1` [build output](https://build.ros.org/view/Nbin_uF64/job/Nbin_uF64__paho-mqtt-cpp__ubuntu_focal_amd64__binary/70/console)

However this minimal docker works just fine:

```
FROM ros:noetic

RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -qqy git fakeroot dpkg-dev debhelper
RUN apt-get install -qqy ros-noetic-paho-mqtt-c
RUN git clone -b debian/noetic/focal/paho-mqtt-cpp https://github.com/nobleo/paho.mqtt.cpp-release

WORKDIR paho.mqtt.cpp-release
RUN apt-get install -qqy apt-src
RUN apt-src import ros-noetic-paho-mqtt-cpp --here --version 1.2.0-2
RUN apt-src build ros-noetic-paho-mqtt-cpp
RUN apt install ../ros-noetic-paho-mqtt-cpp_1.2.0-2focal_amd64.deb
```

The file `libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1` is also present in this dockerfile. And on my laptop upon installing `ros-noetic-paho-mqtt-c`.

Where did the file go on the buildfarm?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389836/%5Bbuildfarm%5D-dpkg-shlibdeps:-error:-cannot-find-library/) by [Timple86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22432/timple86/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2021-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error can occur if the target library is being installed to a directory that dh_shlibdeps doesn't expect.

I first encountered an issue like this one when producing the very first ROS 2 beta 2 debs shortly after joining Open Robotics (and I'm sad to say that in all this time I haven't taken the time to investigate the issue to my satisfaction. We ended up adding patches in the [bloom-generated `debian/rules.em` templates](https://github.com/ros2-gbp/urdfdom-release/commit/19ae1e4e294a07eea277e6b187056c6034b8db77#) which explicitly add the directory containing the "missing" library to the dh_shlibdeps search string.

We used to add these patches to affected packages' bloom templates for each new rosdistro's bootstrap process but discovered that no patch is needed when building on/for Ubuntu 18.04. I'm sad to say that I assumed the change was a "bug fix" in the build pipeline and didn't follow up at all and so I was quite surprised to see the problem return in Ubuntu 20.04.

I think a patch similar to the one above to the `debian/rules.em` template file in your bloom repository will resolve the issue but I don't have a deeper understanding of the problem to know if there's a "better" solution out there. If I ever dive into this mystery I will come back and update the answer.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2021-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Timple86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22432/timple86/) on 2021-11-08**:
This indeeds solved the issue.

> If I ever dive into this mystery I will come back and update the answer.

Please do :)